# get value from hash table

Tags: c++, hashtable

```
Ticket* Championship::findTicketByFanID(unsigned int id) {

    hTabTickets::iterator it = tickets.begin();

    while(it != tickets.end()) {
        if(it->getOwnerID() == id)
            return it;
    }

}
```

Hello there

I'd like to return the object that is on **iterator** it. **tickets** is an hash table that holds objects of the type **Ticket**. When I search for that, there is any solution to return that object?

I want to be able to do this so I can do `Ticket t1 = findTicketByFan(id);`

hTabTickets:

```
struct eqTicket {
    bool operator() (const Ticket &b1, const Ticket &b2) const{
        return b1.getID() == b2.getID();
    }
};

struct hTicket{
    int operator() (const Ticket &b1) const{
        return b1.getID();
    }


};

typedef tr1::unordered_set<Bilhete, hTicket, eqTicket> hTabTickets;
```

Regards

Comment: `return it->second;`

Comment: And you don't have all control paths covered. Please, show the precise type of `hTabTickets`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want this:

```
Ticket* Championship::findTicketByFanID(unsigned int id) {
  for (hTabTickets::iterator it = tickets.begin(); it != tickets.end(); ++it) {
      if(it->getOwnerID() == id)
          return &(*it);
  }
  return NULL;
}
```

If you search for an id very frequently, you may want to change that `set` for a `map`.

Comment: invalid conversion from 'const Ticket*' to 'Ticket*' [-fpermissive]

Comment: If `tickets` or `findTicketByFanID` is `const`, you can't (or shouldn't) return a non-const pointer. Change the return type of the function to `const Ticket*`.

Answer (score 0):

References come to a great use here. Typically returning a local pointer is not a good idea. An example for your case is given below. Two problems with your the code: (a) not all paths return value and (b) hash table should locate quickly (ideally O(1)), so looping is a bad idea. Further, `it` is not being incremented in the loop.

```
class Campeonato {
    // Using STL hashmap
    map<unsigned int, int> tickets;

    public:       
    // the return value tells you whether to use iterator or not.
    bool findTicketByFanID(unsigned int id, map<unsigned int, int>::iterator &it) {
        // std::map provides method find
        it = tickets.find(id);
        if (it != tickets.end())
            return true;

        return false;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to be able to do this so I can do Ticket t1 = findTicketByFan(id);

If it is your intention, return type is not correct, it should return by value or (const) reference, not pointer. Another issue, you use `std::unordered::set` and try to search in a loop, but you should use `std::unordered_set::find()` instead:

```
Ticket Championship::findTicketByFanID(unsigned int id) 
{
    hTabTickets::iterator it = tickets.find( Ticket( id ) );
    if( it == tickets.end() ) // not found do something
        throw std::runtime_error( "Ticket not found" );
    return *it;
}
```

if creating temporary ticket is too expensive, you should use `std::unordered_map<int,Ticket>` instead and use id as a key. Then this function would be:

```
Ticket Championship::findTicketByFanID(unsigned int id) 
{
    hTabTickets::iterator it = tickets.find( id );
    if( it == tickets.end() ) // not found do something
        throw std::runtime_error( "Ticket not found" );
    return it->second;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
hTabTickets::iterator it = tickets.begin()
```

'it' variable's type neither a Ticket, neither a Ticket*, it's a pair which contains key and value variables, you are using it wrong, probably you need to write:

```
it->second
```

to access the Ticket itself